# a goose to something

Tags: meaning

Example:

> Because all that progress has been made in baby steps. All science progress is 99% incremental – a tweak in design here, a bump in power there, **a goose to speed** over here, all occasionally given a huge, mind-bending boost by a theory of evolution, the unraveling of DNA, or the invention of the laser. The big developments might pull in the headlines like a black hole, but it's the constant small, day-to-day improvements that have the most immediate impact on what we do. In this chapter we'll look at some less-than-monumental ways in which computer storage – always the laggard in computing speed – has constantly improved by tids and bits.

What do you think this expression means? Searched in the dictionaries and couldn't find anything that at least remotely talked about the word *goose* as it's used in the example above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Goose* can be a verb, which means (among other things)

> [to increase the activity, speed, power, intensity, or amount of :  spur (an effort to goose newsstand sales)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/goose)

(scroll down to where it defines the verb)

In this passage, *goose* is the noun form of this verb. One of the incremental improvements made by science is a jolt of extra speed in this or that application.

Comment: +1  This is an informal expression.  I would expect to hear it used by someone describing a tweak they made to their soap-box derby race car: _She's running pretty well now.  I tightened up the steering and goosed the engine a little bit, and now she should be able to beat Joe Blow and his team._

Comment: @Adam Stock car, I think; soap-box derby cars have no engines. :0

Comment: Good point - I was thinking of competitive go-kart racing, not SBD.  http://worldkarting.com/

Comment: @StoneyB - That's quite a goose, putting an engine in a soap-box car!

Answer (score -3):

The expression "**a goose to speed over**" probably is a metaphor that describes an obstacle to be overcome.  Converted to a more understandable form, it's

> A goose *over which* to speed (when driving a vehicle)

Comment: This is totally wrong, but I really wish it wasn't, because that would be an awesome derivation  :-)